# Is $\frac{x^2+4x+7}{x^2+x+1}$ a one-to-one function or not?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

Is $\frac{x^2+4x+7}{x^2+x+1}$ a one-to-one function or not?

Leaving aside the graphical method is there any other way in which I can do this question?

Comment: Let the fraction be $f(x)$. Assume $f(a) = f(b)$, can you prove $a = b$?

Comment: I am getting X=Y but there is also another term which is left aside

Comment: That term is XY+2(X+Y)+1=0 and in this when I put x=y i am getting two real roots.

Comment: It's many -one if domain is $R$

Comment: You should then resolve to $Y=-\frac{2X+1}{X+2}$ for distinct pairs of arguments with the same value.

Comment: Let the expression equal to 2 and you'll see that you have then a quadratic equation which can be solved for two real values of $x$

Comment: In this case $f(1)=f(-1)=4$, given that $f(x)=(x^2+4x+7)/(x^2+x+1)$.

Answer (score 3):

Since $\lim_{x\to+\infty }f(x)=\lim_{x\to -\infty }f(x)=1$ and that $f(0)=7$, the injectivity looks complicate :D

Comment: function is many one,not one -one!

Comment: How sir? And why 2?

Comment: Because if the expression satisfies $4-2\sqrt3<\frac{x^2+4x+7}{x^2+x+1}<4+2\sqrt3$ ,then the quadratic equation thus obtained in $x$ can be solved for two real values of $x$

Comment: Take for example $g(x)=f(x)-5$ and using the intermediate value theorem , prove that there is an $y\in ]-\infty ,0[$ and a $z\in]0,\infty [$ such that $g(y)=g(z)$. But $y\neq z$ !

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Let $f$ be the function in question.  Note that the denominator has no roots in $\mathbb{R}$, so $f$ is defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$.  Now recall that a continuous function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is one-to-one iff it is strictly increasing or strictly decreasing.  Since $f$ is differentiable, what does this say about $f'$?

Answer (score 0):

An algebraic approach:

The function is one-one if the equation in $x$
$$
k=\dfrac{x^2+4x+7}{x^2+x+1}
$$
has only one solution for any $k$ that gives real solutions.

Since $x^2+x+1 \ne 0$ we have:

$$
x^2(k-1)+x(k-4)+k-7=0
$$

and we can easely see that the discriminant of this equation can be positive, so there is some $k$ (exactly: $4-2\sqrt{3}<k<4+2\sqrt{3} $) for which we have two values of $x$ and the function is not one to one.